# Django indexing the variable

Tags: django

Simple problem, big headache.

html:

```
{% for file in files %}

    {{ file.image }}

{% endfor %}
```

output:

```
pdf/filename.jpg
```

What I need:

```
filename.jpg
```

What I tried:

```
{% for file in files %}

    {{ file.image[XYZ:XYZ] }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't do processing in the template. This kind of operation should be carried out in the view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way, just in case someone is facing the same problem. (or for myself later in the future :) )

views.py:

```
def cut(value, arg):
    return value.replace(arg, '')
```

html:

```
{% for file in files %}

    {{ file.image|cut:'pdf/ }}

{% endfor %}
```